# Using a Live Google Form inputs for calculations

Tags: google-forms

1. Spreadsheet is not recording responses from form
2. I am able to see from responses appear fleetingly before they vanish. They are however indicated in summary
3. I have tried un-linking, re-linking, changing the destination folder, downloading it as a .CSV, nothing works
4. This issue comes when you link the live form spreadsheet to other spreadsheets. I am using the arrayformula and query functions to export from a live spreadsheet.

Please suggest a resolution.

Comment: Google Forms are are not linked to "destination folders". Responses are stored in with the form and alternative could use a Google Sheets file as destination. 
Google Forms have "live" collaboration to edit responses, but not for responding.
Maybe you are sharing the form instead of sending it to the respondents. Consider to create an a form example a share the link here.